# Convert List(object) to Object

Tags: c#, .net-core

I have a WebAPI project without ORM (direct in the Database). I use lists to receive data from database (for example):

```
public List<Numerador_mdfe> Numerador_Get_id()
    {
        List<DbParameter> parameterList = new List<DbParameter>();
        List<Numerador_mdfe> Numerador_Lista = new List<Numerador_mdfe>();
        Numerador_mdfe Numerador = null;

        string sql = "SELECT top 1 Numerador001,Numerador002,acesso FROM Numerador_mdfe order by Numerador001";
        using (DbDataReader dataReader = base.GetDataReader(sql,
                                                            parameterList,
                                                            CommandType.Text))
        {
            if (dataReader != null && dataReader.HasRows)
            {
                while (dataReader.Read())
                {
                    Numerador = new Numerador_mdfe();
                    Numerador.Numerador001 = (string)dataReader["Numerador001"].ToString().Trim();
                    Numerador.Numerador002 = Convert.ToInt32(dataReader["Numerador002"]);
                    Numerador.acesso = Convert.ToString(dataReader["acesso"].ToString().Trim());
                    Numerador_Lista.Add(Numerador);
                }
            }
        }
        return Numerador_Lista;
    }
```

However, in a routine I look for the list:

```
DAO_Bases Base = new DAO_Bases();
List<Model.Numerador_mdfe> MDFE_NG;
MDFE_NG = Base.Numerador_Get_id();
```

Is there a simple way to transform the list of type Numerator_mdfe into an Numerator_mdfe object?

Or just using for each and adding?

In these cases, it will always return only one record.

Comment: `Numerator_mdfe` is **an object**, it's a `List<Numerador_mdfe>`, your question is unclear to me. *You* could however derive from `List` and create your own, but that's non-sense.

Comment: Id guess its moaning about MDFE_NG = Base.Numerador_Get_id(); because MDFE_NG is supposed to be a list and Id guess Base.Numerador-Get_id returns 1 id

Comment: Could you please specify how do you want to transform list of object to a single object of same type?

Comment: This looks like the kind of boilerplate more conveniently handled with [Dapper](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper) than with roll-your-own code. That also solves the problem of whether to retrieve one or multiple objects by varying the type.

Comment: In this case, it will always bring only one record.Is there a way to convert a list to an object without using 'for each'?

Comment: one error try this: Cannot implicitly convert type 'NF_NG.Model.NFE_MDFE_NG[]' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<NF_NG.Model.NFE_MDFE_NG>'

Comment: In the above case you will **always** return one, if anything exists. So why even try and return a `List<T>` clearly when this routine will only ever return one? If this is the case, create another routine, one that return's a `List<T>` and another that returns `Model.Numerador_mdfe`. A side note: your not using params either, why pass an object if not using them?

Comment: It is a web Api. I have a controller that returns too. I would not want to create one method as a list and another as an object. I would like to convert the list directly as an object, so if you need to in other cases. if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Return only the selected object and not the object list:

```
public Numerador_mdfe Numerador_Get_id()
{
        List<DbParameter> parameterList = new List<DbParameter>();
        Numerador_mdfe Numerador =null;

        string sql = "SELECT top 1 Numerador001,Numerador002,acesso FROM Numerador_mdfe order by Numerador001";
        using (DbDataReader dataReader = base.GetDataReader(sql,
                                                            parameterList,
                                                            CommandType.Text))
        {
            if (dataReader != null && dataReader.HasRows)
            {
                if (dataReader.Read())
                {
                    Numerador = new Numerador_mdfe();
                    Numerador.Numerador001 = dataReader["Numerador001"]?.ToString().Trim();
                    Numerador.Numerador002 = Convert.ToInt32(dataReader["Numerador002"]);
                    Numerador.acesso = dataReader["acesso"]?.ToString().Trim();
                    Numerador_Lista.Add(Numerador);
                }
            }
        }
    return Numerador ;
}
```

I ignored other apparent code problems